# Laravel Send Birthday Reminder email Using Mailables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am building an application which suppose to send birthday reminder email to users . Everything was working fine with laravel 5.2 , but now i want to use Mailables i don't know where to loop users . Here is my Mailable Class ..

```
namespace App\Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
class BirthdayReminder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $user;
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->User = $user;
    }
    public function build()
    {
        $users = User::whereMonth('dob', '=', date('m'))->whereDay('dob', '=', date('d'))->get(); 
         foreach($users as $user) {    
          return $this->from('info@bandali.co.tz')
        ->view('emails.birthday')
        ->with(['user' => $user]);
    }

    }
}
```

Here is my command to send birthday

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\BirthdayReminder;
use Mail;
use App;
class SendBirthdayReminderEmail extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'email:birthday';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Email users a birthday Reminder message';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

   /*  $users = User::whereMonth('dob', '=', date('m'))->whereDay('dob', '=', date('d'))->get();   
    foreach($users as $user) {   
         // send an email to "batman@batcave.io"
        Mail::to('robertrutenge@gmail.com')->queue(new BirthdayReminder($user));


     }
     */
     $email="xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
     Mail::to($email)->send(new BirthdayReminder());

    $this->info('Birthday messages sent successfully!');

    }
}
```

And here is my view

```
<p>Hello Admin,</p>
<p>Today is {{$user['first_name']}} Birthday . Please take time and  wish  a happy birthday!</p>
```

My Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //

      Commands\SendBirthdayReminderEmail::class,

    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
         $schedule->command('email:birthday')->everyMinute()->timezone('Africa/Dar_es_Salaam');
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I want to check in the database if there is any user with birthday , then send the email to one or more users . If None , then do nothing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Command file

```
public function handle()
{ 
   $i = 0;
   $users = User::whereMonth('dob', '=', date('m'))->whereDay('dob', '=', date('d'))->get();  

   foreach($users as $user)
   {
       $email="xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
       Mail::to($email)->send(new BirthdayReminder($user));
       $i++; 
   }

   $this->info($i.' Birthday messages sent successfully!');
}
```

In your Mailable class

```
 public $user;
 public function __construct($user)
 {
     $this->user = $user;
 }

 public function build()
 {
  $user = $this->user;
  return $this->from('info@bandali.co.tz')
              ->view('emails.birthday',compact('user'));
 }
```

In your blade file (birthday.blade.php)

```
<p>Hello Admin,</p>
   <p>Today is {{ $user->first_name }} Birthday. Please take time and wish a happy birthday!</p>
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping . Everything seems to work ok until i go to my gmail and i got no email . The Cron Job returns this Running scheduled command: '/opt/php70/bin/php' 'artisan' email:birthday > '/dev/null' 2>&1 & . So , somehow , the command is executed without sending any email .

Comment: Have you check do you have any user. you can do `Log::info($user);` within loop in handle method and check laravel.log file. I guess there is no user otherwise it should send.

Comment: Just run `php artisan email:birthday` from your root directory of project and check what is printing in log and check in command prompt what is coming as info message. ?. please tell me

Comment: I checked and there is one user

Comment: Remove `Queueable` from your mailable class and run the php artisan command manually. I think there is no problem with code. I think your mail is going into the queue. please repose.

Comment: sure @bobin56 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134812/discussion-between-bobin56-and-vikash).